# Add a class to every child of a slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to set up a component with a slot, that when rendered adds a class to every children of that slot. In a very simplified manner:

```
<template>
<div>
  <slot name="footerItems"></slot>
</div>
</template>
```

How would I go about this? My current solution is to add the class to the elements in an `onBeforeUpdate` hook:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useSlots, onMounted, onBeforeUpdate } from 'vue';

onBeforeUpdate(() => addClassToFooterItems());
onMounted(() => addClassToFooterItems());

function addClassToFooterItems() {
  const slots = useSlots();

  if (slots && slots.footerItems) {
    for (const item of slots.footerItems()) {
      item.el?.classList.add("card-footer-item");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

However, the elements lose the styling whenever it's rerendered (using `npm run serve`) and also jest tests give me a warning:

```
    [Vue warn]: Slot "footerItems" invoked outside of the render function: this will not track dependencies used in the slot. Invoke the slot function inside the render function instead.
```

Should I move the slot to its own component and use a render function there? But even then I'm not sure how to edit the children to add the classes or how to produce several root level elements from the render function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I managed to solve this in an incredibly hacky way, but at least my issue with re-rendering doesn't happen anymore and jest doesn't complain. I wrote a component with a render function that appends that class to all children

```
<template>
<render>
  <slot></slot>
</render>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useSlots } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps<{
  childrenClass: string;
}>();

function recurseIntoFragments(element: any): any {
  if (element.type.toString() === 'Symbol(Fragment)'
    && element.children[0].type.toString() === 'Symbol(Fragment)'
  ) {
    return recurseIntoFragments(element.children[0]);
  } else {
    return element;
  }
}

const render = () => {

  const slot = useSlots().default!();
  recurseIntoFragments(slot[0]).children.forEach((element: any) => {
    if (element.props?.class && !element.props?.class.includes(props.childrenClass)) {
      element.props.class += ` ${props.childrenClass}`;
    } else {
      element.props.class = props.childrenClass;
    }
  });

  return slot;
}
</script>
```

Then I would just wrap the slot in this component to add the class to the children elements:

```
<template>
<div>
  <classed-slot childrenClass="card-footer-item">
    <slot name="footerItems"></slot>
  </classed-slot>
</div>
</template>
```

I would gladly accept any answer that improves upon this solution, especially:

- Any tips to type it. All those `any`s feel wonky but I find it very impractical working with Vue types for slots since they are usually unions of 3 or 4 types and the only solution is to wrap these in type checks
- Anything that improves its reliability since it seems that it'd crash in any slightly different setup than the one I intended
- Any recommendation based on Vue's (or TS) best practices, since this looks very amateurish.
- Really any other way to test for symbol equality because I know none

**EDIT**
This is my latest attempt, a render function in a file `ClassedSlot.js`:

```js
import { cloneVNode } from 'vue';

function recursivelyAddClass(element, classToAdd) {
  if (Array.isArray(element)) {
    return element.map(el => recursivelyAddClass(el, classToAdd));
  } else if (element.type.toString() === 'Symbol(Fragment)') {
    const clone = cloneVNode(element);
    clone.children = recursivelyAddClass(element.children, classToAdd)
    return clone;
  } else {
    return cloneVNode(element, { class: classToAdd });
  }
}

export default {
  props: {
    childrenClass: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
  },

  render() {
    const slot = this.$slots.default();

    return recursivelyAddClass(slot, this.$props.childrenClass);
  },
};
```

The usage of this component is exactly the same as in the previous one. I'm kinda happy with this solution, seems more robust and idiomatic. Note that it's javascript because I found it really hard to type these functions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@Haf 's answer is good.
I made some adjustments, so that you can specify the component name.

```
import { FunctionalComponent, StyleValue, cloneVNode, Ref, ComputedRef, unref } from "vue";

type MaybeRef<T> = T | Ref<T>;

/**
 * @param extraProps - ref or normal object
 * @returns
 * 
 * @example
 * 
 * const StyleComponent = useCssInJs({class: 'text-red-500'});
 * 
 * const ComponentA = () => {
 *  return <StyleComponent><span>text is red-500</span></StyleComponent>
 * }
 */
export const useCssInJs = (extraProps: MaybeRef<{
  class?: string,
  style?: StyleValue
}>) => {
  const FnComponent: FunctionalComponent = (_, { slots }) => {
    const defaultSlot = slots.default?.()[0];
    // could be Fragment or others? I'm just ignoring these case here
    if (!defaultSlot) return;
    const node = cloneVNode(defaultSlot, unref(extraProps));
    return [node];
  };

  return FnComponent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution with TS

```
<template>
  <render>
    <slot></slot>
  </render>
</template>

<script setup lang='ts'>
import { cloneVNode, useAttrs, useSlots, type VNode } from 'vue'

const att = useAttrs()

function recursivelyAddProps(element: VNode): VNode | Array<VNode> {
  if (Array.isArray(element?.children)) {
    return element.children.map((el) => recursivelyAddProps(el as VNode)) as Array<VNode>
  } else {
    return cloneVNode(element, att)
  }
}

const render = () => {
  const slot = useSlots()?.default!()
  return recursivelyAddProps(slot[0])
}
</script>
```

And usage

```
<ExtendedSlot class='dropdown-item'>
    <slot></slot>
</ExtendedSlot>
```